# How to have a view field that searches node title, body and everything about node

Tags: views, search

I am looking at replacing the core search module with a custom view. I would want a field that lets users search all the content by keyword(s).

What's my best option, preferably a module that does this in a user friendly way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using Apache Solr backend. You can use the following modules:

- http://drupal.org/project/search_api
- http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr

Another solution is to use a module like "views_or" or "views_filters_populate".

Otherwise you could give a try to "search_autocomplete".

Good work!